# Does it matter where you go to undergraduate if you want to get into a good grad school?

Tags: graduate-school, undergraduate

I graduated high school with a good GPA that could have gotten me into some better schools. However, my parents did not have the money to pay the college tuition as well as the room and board costs. I had to stay and commute to the nearest college which is Kent State University for a BA in Teaching English as a Second Language (TESL) with a minor in Japanese. I'm currently in my sophomore year and doing very well. I'm holding a 3.5 GPA average right now. My question is: does going to a less prestigious school such as Kent State affect me for getting into top graduate programs such as Ivy Leagues or other colleges that are at the top of the lists when it comes to my graduate program that I want to attend?

Comment: FYI: [Dataset of grad admission acceptance rate based on undergrad school](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/61203/452)